# Import Xcode file into Intel XDK

Tags: ios, xcode, intel-xdk

So I am looking into developing an app with codea which is a code editor app with very good reviews. It exports as a zip that can then be opened in Xcode for release. I however, use Intel XDK as it is free, and want to know if I can open the Xcode file in that in order to publish it. (Yes I am aware that XDK does not publish to the App Store but I am ok with that) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Intel XDK only supports the development of HTML5 apps, it does not support development of XCode apps or Objective C code.